Is there a way to open developer tools on an iPad without a Mac?
I don’t mind if I have to install another browser, I just want to be able to see and use developer tools. In particular the ability to view and edit the source code of a web page, and access the browser and error console.
I tried Firefox for iOS and Google Chrome, but to no avail.
I can technically see the source code through the ‘Shortcuts’ app, and probably with BeautifulSoup and requests, but it’s just not the same the full developer tools in a browser and there is no console.
